# Redux return and change state with ... dots

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

i cant understand what am i doing wrong 
i tried to change the users on the state object into the new users

```
const initialState = {
  users:{},
}


const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    if (action.type == "FETCH_USERS") {

        return {
            ...state,
            users: action.payload
        }
    }

    return state;
}
```

and the error is

```
ERROR in ./index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/app/index.js: Unexpected token (77:12)

  75 |
  76 |         return {
> 77 |             ...state,
     |             ^
  78 |             users: action.payload
  79 |         }
  80 |     }
```

Comment: you should be using babel or some other library in order to compile es6 back to es5. Are you doing it?

Comment: yes im using babel-preset-es2015  @Patryk

Comment: @T.J. Crowder
my package.json

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.0"
  }

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thanks for letting me know, I didn't know that

Comment: @Patryk: I mis-remembered, btw; I don't know whether object spread will be in ES2017, it's still at Stage 3 and here we are at the end of February, June's right around the corner...

Answer (score 2):

You've said you're using the `es2015` Babel preset. That syntax isn't part of ES2015; ES2015 has *iterable spread* syntax but not *object spread* ([spread properties](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread)) syntax. You should be using the [`react` preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/), which has had these for a long time (or you could use the `stage-3` preset, as spread properties are Stage 3 now).

Comment: im using babel-preset-react is that enough?

Comment: @דניאללביא: Then the file isn't being transpiled before whatever it is that's giving you the error.